# Integer length right triangle with hypotenuse $2^{100}$

Tags: geometry

> Is it possible to construct a right triangle with integer side lengths and a hypotenuse of $2^{100}$?

After looking at a list of pythagorean triples, I couldn't find a hypotenuse of a right triangle with integer side lengths that was a power of $2$. So I would be inclined to think the answer to this question is no. I was thinking of using a modular arithmetic argument to show that $a^2 + b^2 \neq 2^{200}$ for any positive integers $a,b$, but I couldn't find a mod that would work (I tried $3,4,5,6,7$).

Comment: If the hypotenuse is length $2^{100}$ then the equation should be $a^2+b^2=(2^{100})^2=2^{200}$

Comment: @ASKASK : You can code $2^{100}$ in MathJax as 2^{100}. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy bad, I'm on mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hypotenuse is either the largest of a primitive Pythagorean triple, or a multiple of one.

The largest number in a primitive triple is always odd.

Does $2^{100}$ have any odd factors?

EDIT: because I was asked, adding a quick proof that of primitive triple $(a,b,c)$ with $c > \max(a,b)$, $c$ is always odd.

Consider $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

First observe that both $a$ and $b$ can't both be even, because both sides would be even, and since they have a common factor, this is not a primitive triple.

So either $a$ and $b$ are both odd or they have different parities.

Suppose the former. Then the $LHS$ would be $2 \pmod 4$, while the $RHS$ would be $0 \pmod 4$, giving a contradiction.

So the latter has to be the case. The sum of an even and an odd number is always odd, giving the required proof.

Comment: Why is it always odd?

Comment: @user19405892 Added a quick proof.

Comment: Why does a multiple of the largest of a pythagorean triple have to be odd? You seem to be claiming that $2^{100}$ must be the hypotenuse in a primitive pythagorean triple.

Comment: I never claimed that a multiple of the largest of a PPT has to be odd - it can very well be even - nor that $2^{100}$ necessarily has to be the largest of a PPT. The hypotenuse of a right triangle with integer sides is always *either* the largest of a PPT *or* an integer multiple of the largest of a PPT. $2^{100}$ is clearly even, so it can't be the largest of a PPT. That leaves the second case to be tested. For the second case to hold, *at least one factor* of $2^{100}$ has to be odd (namely the largest of the PPT under consideration). I asked you if $2^{100}$ has *any* odd factors at all?

Comment: (except $1$ of course, that should be obvious and trivial).

Comment: @user19405892 Have you got it now? Has this helped you or do you need further clarification?

Comment: @user19405892 You're welcome.